# Copy a file from one folder to another by matching a string in a file name and rename the copied file by appending date and time to the file name

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I need to copy my server log file to another folder up on completion of one log file and then rename the copied file adding date and time to the file name.

**Source :** C:\Server\Logs

**Destination :** Can be selected by user using .BrowseForFolder

**Log file name :** `Server_log_23.txt` ("23" is the log number which will change from 1 to 30)

One log file will be completed in 2 minutes and log writing will be moved to next file by adding one (that means if `Server_log_23.txt` is completed then server will starts writing logs in `Server_logs_24.txt`  till `Server_log_30.txt`, if log_30 is completed then it will starts writing in `log_1`)

Comment: any one has any idea to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a code like this, but it is not giving a continuous loop

```
 Const DestinationFile = "C:\Users\Testbench\Desktop\file copy\Destination\"

 Const src = "C:\Users\Testbench\Desktop\file copy\Source\"

 strInput = UserInput( "Please enter file number:" )

 strInput1 = "log_(" &strInput1 &")"

 Dim sDateTimeStamp

 Dim folder

 Sub CopyFile()`enter code here`
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     srcfile = strInput
     Set folder = fso.GetFolder(src)
     For Each file In folder.files 
     If instr(file.name, strInput) > 0 Then
        srcfile=file.name
        WScript.Echo srcfile
     End If 
 Next
SourceFile= "C:\Users\Testbench\Desktop\file copy\Source\" & srcfile
WScript.Echo SourceFile

sDateTimeStamp = cStr(Year(now())) & _
             Pad(cStr(Month(now())),2) & _
             Pad(cStr(Day(now())),2) & _
             Pad(cStr(Hour(now())),2) & _
             Pad(cStr(Minute(now())),2) & _
             Pad(cStr(Second(now())),2)


WScript.Echo "Copying " & SourceFile & " to " & DestinationFile
fso.CopyFile SourceFile, DestinationFile & srcfile & "_" & sDateTimeStamp & ".txt", True

Set fso = Nothing
End Sub

Function Pad(CStr2Pad, ReqStrLen)
    Dim Num2Pad
    Pad = CStr2Pad
    If len(CStr2Pad) < ReqStrLen Then
        Num2Pad = String((ReqStrlen - Len(CStr2Pad)), "0")
        Pad = Num2Pad & CStr2Pad
    End If
End Function

Function UserInput( myPrompt )
    If UCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\CSCRIPT.EXE" Then
        WScript.StdOut.Write myPrompt & " "
        UserInput = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine
    Else
        UserInput = InputBox( myPrompt )
    End If
End Function

Do while strInput1<30
   wscript.sleep 180
   CopyFile()
   strInput1 = strInput1 + 1
Exit Do
   strInput1 =1
   CopyFile()
   strInput1 = strInput1 + 1
Loop
```